# Is it idiomatic to say "don't bite me in the arm"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

We can say "**[to poke me in the arm](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/poke)**" as stated in dictionaries.

the verb "**bite**" is somehow similar to "**poke**" in its meaning because both mean to push into or through something.

But I don't see the structure "**[to bite somebody in the eye/arm](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/poke)**" in dictionaries.

> [bite](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/bite_1?q=bite) [intransitive, transitive] to use your teeth to cut into or
>   through something
>
> Does your dog bite?
>
> Come here! I won't bite! (= you don't need to be afraid)
>
> **bite into/through something** She bit into a ripe juicy pear.
>
> **bite somebody/something** She was bitten by the family dog.
>
> Stop biting your nails!
>
> **bite off something/sth off** He bit off a large chunk of bread/He bit a
>   large chunk of bread off.

---

It seems that the dictionary suggests to use "**to bite something**", for example, "**to bite the arm/ the leg/ etc**"

or, "**to bite into something**", for example, "**to bite into the arm/ the leg/ etc**".

But they don't have examples of "**to bite somebody into something**".

Is it idiomatic to say "**don't bite me in the arm**"?

Comment: Yes, you can say that.

Comment: I think "It bit me on the arm" is more usual than "It bit me in the arm." I've never heard "Don't bite me in the arm." We get hit *in* the face, the eye, the mouth, the groin and the tummy, but *on* the head, the back, the leg, the foot and the arm. And I think biting follows similar rules!

Comment: Or just "it bit my arm."

Comment: Frankly speaking, if the verb 'bite'  collocates with prepositional phrases with the head word 'in', it is a sign of erroneous usage, in the UK, for example. The reason is one well-known idiom that makes everyone smile, if somebody says something like 'don't bite me in ...' The accepted usage of the verb 'bite' is with a direct object or prepositional phrase having other head words. Though, such usage is accepted in some other countries where this idiom is unknown.

Answer (score 1):

Your construction is grammatically valid, but it would be more idiomatic to say “don’t bite my arm!”

The only idiomatic use of “bite me in” is the idiom “bite [person] in the ass”.

Answer (score -1):

No, this construction is impossible as idiomatic in the modern USA and UK variants of English. The verb *bite* has a large number of idiomatic grammar constructions and idiomatic expressions. All have been defined by its use for many years. Therefore, they are stable with their meaning in the modern usage. The expression *don't bite me in the arm* is the result of so called *logical intersection* of two well-known grammar constructions with own established meaning, if we take it as an idiom. That is why it could be totally incomprehensible as idiomatic for the native American and British English speakers.

Though, it is fairly possible that such construction could be acceptable as an idiom in some variants of minor dialects and slang of English in these countries.

Comment: Very good answer, but it’s worth stressing that although it’s not idiomatic, it’s always an acceptable *construction*.

Comment: Agree. Though, the question was about idiomacy of the construction, as it seemed to me.

Comment: Yes, true, but it’s best to avoid confusion :D

Comment: )  Nothing to argue about.

Comment: The use of both "impossible" (it is possible) and "totally incomprehensible" (the phrase is quite understandable) not only overstates the situation, but actually contradicts the final paragraph in the answer. And while I don't personally disagree with the *general* assertion, some kind of demonstration of objective evidence for the statement (a dictionary definition, an article that describes prepositions in this context, or a Google Ngram Viewer result, for instance) would go a long way to making this more than just an unsupported personal opinion.

Comment: But, ' bite somebody in the arm' is not an idiom. It is common English. The topic is 'is it idiomatic to say.' Or, is the phrasing an idiom? It is not. Or, it may be so that you follow one of four definitions of the term 'idiomatic' with the sense that I didn't use here.

Comment: @kngram _Idiomatic_ does not only mean ‘as a (fixed) idiom’ – it also means ‘natural and unremarkable, as spoken by a native speaker’. It is not idiomatic (= the natural phrasing a native speaker would use), but it is perfectly possible (a native speaker _might_ use it occasionally), and it is completely comprehensible and unambiguous (no native speaker would ever be perplexed by it or unable to understand it if they heard it).

Comment: ...'Or, it may be so that you follow one of four definitions of the term 'idiomatic' with the sense that I didn't use here. ' I already wrote about it. Thanks.

Comment: First, *bit me in the butt* is absolutely idiomatic. It's used when something you do backfires and has negative consequences for you. For actual, physical, bites, *bit me in the arm* is less common than *bit me on the arm*, but it's not "totally incomprehensible". If you said it, any native English speaker would know exactly what you meant.

Comment: To be short and to the point, *to bite smb in the arm* is not an idiom in modern English. It's just the example of an unusual prepositional phrase in such construction. Just imagine, somebody asked you to explain a possible meaning of the "idiom" *to bite smb in the arm*. You would very probably smile, and answer, It's a bit of everyday normal speech, though, I would use here the preposition *on* instead of *in*. The intention of the explanation above was the same, although, the style was a bit more regulated.

Comment: Why did I not delete the perfectly right answer of mine? ) Because it is very useful for showing how some 'egghead' could be trapped and ridiculed by some kind of commentators who like doing such things. There is nothing to discuss. It is necessary to write only that: if a subject is a dog in the clause then it will not be an idiomatic pattern. If an insect ‐ it could be.